# Linux open issue

Tags: linux

I am having a problem with "open". even if there is no device named ttyACM3, it does not return an error. it always prints "no error".

What could be the problem ?

```
fd = open("/dev/ttyACM3", O_RDWR);
if(fd)
{
    printf("no error");
}
else
{
    printf("error");
}
```

Comment: Read the specification of `open`, especially the return value section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
if(fd)
```

Would evaluate to true for `fd == -1`, which is how `open` returns an error. `open` returns `-1` on error, not `0`.

In the future read the documentation more carefully :)

Also `if (fd)` evaluates to true for negative numbers, in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 1):

You are not providing the correct condition in if()

open() returns negative value if port doesnt exist.
So the correct code would be

```
if(fd > 0)
```

[This](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/718340/C-program-to-Linux-Serial-port-read-write) tutorial might be useful.